# how can I add arrow in plotly pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, pie-chart

I am trying to represent a pie chart using plotly function to show the arrow of each percentage records. For example, the number of records of %70 is 128456 should show as an arrow with the value representing as seen in the picture [image]
I tried to add some commands in textinfo such as value + percent but it shows me the 30 and %30.

Here is my code so far,

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

moneyFlow = pd.read_excel('moneyFlow.xlsx').drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])
moneyFlow.info()
X = moneyFlow.drop(["Sentiment"], axis=1)
y = moneyFlow["Sentiment"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)



split_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DataSplit': ['Train', 'Test'],
    'Percentage': [round((len(X_train) / len(X)) * 100, 3), round((len(X_test) / len(X)) * 100, 3)],
    'Number of Records': [len(X_train), len(X_test)]
})


fig = px.pie(split_df, values='Percentage', names='DataSplit', color = "DataSplit",
             title='Percentage of Data Split using train_test_split',
             labels={'Percentage': 'Percentage (%)'},
             hover_data=['Number of Records'],
             hole=0.3,color_discrete_map={'Train':'darkblue',
                                          'Test':'royalblue'})



fig.update_traces(textinfo='percent')


fig.show()
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can you explain what you mean by arrow? do you want an arrow that shows up when you hover? perhaps you can upload an image showing the desired outcome to help clarify

Comment: To keep it simple how to show the number of records instead of %70. @DerekO

Comment: I have tried the following. 

text = ('k' + Number of Records for Number of Records in split_df.Number of Records. values 1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
split_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DataSplit': ['Train', 'Test'],
    'Percentage': [round((len(X_train) / len(X)) * 100, 3), round((len(X_test) / len(X)) * 100, 3)],
    'Number of Records': [len(X_train), len(X_test)]
})


fig = px.pie(split_df, values='Percentage', names='DataSplit', color = "DataSplit",
             title='Percentage of Data Split using train_test_split',
             labels={'Percentage': 'Percentage (%)'},
             hover_data=['Number of Records'],
             hole=0.3,color_discrete_map={'Train':'darkblue',
                                          'Test':'royalblue'})



fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='percent', text =split_df['Number of Records'].values )
fig.show()
```

[image]

we can use text command function and extract the information from our dataframe. Hope this help